# UITextField NSForegroundColor turns transparent after screen rotation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am having a problem that the UITextField font foreground color turns transparent after screen rotation. Below is my code.

```
let TextAttributes = [
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : 3.0
]

//In viewDidLoad
textFieldTop.delegate = textFieldTopDelegate
textFieldTop.text = "TOP"
textFieldTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.view.frame.width, 44)
textFieldTop.defaultTextAttributes = TextAttributes
self.view.addSubview(textFieldTop)
textFieldTop.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

textFieldBottom.delegate = textFieldBottomDelegate
textFieldBottom.text = "BOTTOM"
textFieldBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height - 88, self.view.frame.width, 44)
textFieldBottom.defaultTextAttributes = TextAttributes
self.view.addSubview(textFieldBottom)
textFieldBottom.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

//in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
textFieldTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.view.frame.width, 44)
textFieldTop.defaultTextAttributes = TextAttributes
self.view.addSubview(textFieldTop)
textFieldTop.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
textFieldBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height - 88, self.view.frame.width, 44)
textFieldBottom.defaultTextAttributes = TextAttributes
self.view.addSubview(textFieldBottom)
textFieldBottom.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

How can I make sure the foreground text color does not automatically turn transparent after rotation?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I realized my problem does not come from the rotation. For some reason the foregroundcolor is transparent, and it cannot be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set NSStrokeWidthAttributeName to -3

Answer (score 1):

Every Time didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation get call you are adding textFieldTop and textFieldBottom to self, in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation all you need to  do is move and resize the fields:

```
textFieldTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.view.frame.width, 44)
textFieldBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height - 88,  self.view.frame.width, 44)
```

Comment: I realized that my problem does not lie in the rotation, but that when I add an Image to view it does in front of the text. Regardless, you are right I do not need that other code.